# get element as selector in jquery which is loaded after page load

Tags: jquery

I had made one function for making pagination ,sorting and  listing all in one and that function I call on load of page of body like

```
<body onload='MYFUNCTION(parm1,param2,param3)'>
```

Now i want to apply some jquery on the button which shows all document in fancybox which come by that onload but when i try to do on

```
$(function(){
    $(#container).on('click','#button',function(){
        //code here for load fancybox and getting all image stuff by ajax 
    });
});
```

than i not get that element because it cant find it on page load so what can i do 
inshort - **how to select element in jquery which is load after page load**

Thank you..

Comment: So delegate to `document` level. That's said i'm not sure to understand your question...

Comment: When you do delegation with `.on()` the selector on the left should be a static element, the selector in the argument list is the dynamically added element(s).

Comment: thxx for telling me i trying to find it from 2 days on stackoverflow .